# Why is my code finding weird contours in openCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv

```
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    j = 0
    for contour in contours:
        print(j)
        print(str(contour))
        x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contours[j])
        roi = mask[y:y+height, x:x+width]
        cv2.imwrite("roi"+str(j)+".png", roi)
        j+=1
```

I am trying to get this code to save all the contours in the image. This works fairly well, however, two weird contours are being saved along with the ones I expect to be saved, the letters and the crosshair. One of the weird ones is a small white image and for some reason one of the contours is just the whole image.

- [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf3If.png)
- [First weird one (whole image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk2ph.png)
- [Second weird one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X68Pm.png)

Comment: Please post a link to your mask image. Your mask should have the objects for which you want find contours in white and the rest of the image as black. Then find external contours.

Comment: As Fred mentions in the first comment, you should invert your image to find white contours on black background. (1) You get the whole image, because the most outer contour is the one enclosing the whole white background. (2) The small white contour is simply the hole of the letter A. You only get your desired letters, because you're using `cv2.RETR_TREE`, which also finds inner contours w.r.t. some hierarchy. By inverting your image and only finding the external contours using `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` instead, you'll only find the letters.

Comment: @fmw42 the "original" one is the mask one, sorry.

Comment: Please follow the comment from @HansHirse

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the type of contour search as indicated above (`cv2.RETR_TREE` vs `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`), the `cv2.findContours` function finds white blobs over black background. One approach you may take is invert your image prior to searching contours and that will help you find the objects instead of the background. The code below should help you save the letters and crosshair in the image. Attached you can see the image with the output of the contour detection. The contour ROIs are generated with the original image so you get white letters over black background:

```
# If the image is not grayscale, convert to grayscale first and 
# invert so the background is black and objects are white
# mask = ~cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(~mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
output = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
plt.imshow(output)
for j, contour in enumerate(contours):
    x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    roi = mask[y:y+height, x:x+width]
    cv2.imwrite(f"roi_{j}.png", roi)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]